# Solving First order ODE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have an ODE described by

$$\frac{dk}{du} = \frac{\partial(ku-k^3)/\partial u}{V(u) - \partial(ku-k^3)/\partial k} $$

and I try to solve with

```
Dsolve[k'[u] == D[k*u - k^3, u]/(u - D[k*u - k^3, 
k]), u, k]
```

But it tells me off. Why?

Comment: `k` is a function of `u` as it seems. `u` is a function of what?

Comment: What does "it tells me off" mean? I get that it returns without solving the equation, with no messages why. Is that what you get?

Comment: In addition to the comment by @MichaelE2 the way you wrote the o.d.e is very strange. It seems that you are telling `Mma` that k is the independent variable and also k depends on u.

Comment: Apparently, I didn't notice that `DSolve` (capital `S`) was misspelled in the OP. :) Did you use `Dsolve` or `DSolve` when you ran your code? If you get error messages, please include them in the question. Tx.

Comment: Got it now, cheers!

Comment: Where does this equation come from, by the way?  Tx.

Comment: Starting from
$$V(u){dk \over du} = {d \over du} F(k, u) = {\partial F \over \partial k} {dk\over du} + {\partial F \over \partial u} \,,$$
and solving for $dk/du$,
$${dk \over du}
 = \frac{{\partial F}/{\partial u}}{V(u)-{\partial F}/{\partial k}} \,,$$
we obtain the OP's ODE by setting $F(k,u)=ku-k^3$, which is the equation solved in Andre's answer with $V=u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DSolve[k'[u] == D[k[u]*u - k[u]^3, u]/(u - D[k[u]*u - k[u]^3, k[u]]), 
 k[u], u]
```

This could work. The `k` need to be writen as `k[u]`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try that one?

```
D[k*u - k^3, u]/(u - D[k*u - k^3, k]);

DSolve[k'[u] == 1/(3 k[u]), k[u], u]
```

Comment: This seems to be incorrect as k is a function of u, which will give you a completely different equation. See the other answer.

Comment: @Dunlop I think this is right, if $V(u)=u$ and the partial derivatives mean what they appear to mean in the TeX in the OP. There's some ambiguity about their meaning, but treating the dependent variable as a variable happens from time to time. Think $m x''(t) = -\partial U/\partial x$ where $U$ is the potential energy, for instance.

Comment: As Dunlop sad, I used the partial derivatives only in explicit variables.

Comment: I guess it then depends a bit on what he OP actually wanted which is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Or even if they know what they want....I mean, what are the chances that the numerator should have been $d(ku-k^3)/du$, as in the other answer, but the denominator should be a partial derivative of the same function?